# Binding to an array

Tags: wpf, arrays, binding, datatemplate

I added a custom control library to my project and in that control there is an array `DependencyProperty`. Now when I try to bind that property in the client I get:

> Tags of type 'PropertyArrayStart' are not supported in template sections.

The message is self explanatory but how do you set array properties in a `DataTemplate`?

Comment: Can you provide an example in your question; it will help you get a better answer and not waste anyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `IMultiValueConverter` to build an array from multiple bindings. A `converter` is only required as you cannot use a `MultiBinding` without one.

```
public class MultipleValuesToArrayConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.ToArray();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to bind an array from the code behind to the dependency property which is an array of the same type so there is no conversion required.